# Looking to initialise every view with a List no matter the entry point of the site

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, shopping-cart

I have a Shopping Basket which holds selected items by the user and is stored in a session variable. I'd like this to show various values on every view about the basket state i.e. basket:1, but I can only see how to pass this to a view at a single entry point. How would I initialise every view with this List?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could render a [`child action`](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) in your Layout. The idea of a child action is that it could execute some logic in parallel to the main action.

For example you could have the following controller:

```
public class ShoppingBasketInfoController: Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = Session["info"] as ShoppingInfoViewModel;
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

and then you will have a corresponding partial view (`~/Views/ShoppingBasketInfo/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model ShoppingInfoViewModel
<div>
    You have @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.NbProducts) in your basket
</div>
```

and then you could find an appropriate place in your Layout to render this action:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "ShoppingBasketInfo")
```

Now all your views will have this information shown at the specified location without worrying about where this information is coming from, how is it stored or what view model it uses. The main actions are completely independent.

I have decorated the child action with the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute to ensure that this action will never be accessible through a normal HTTP request from the client using for example `/ShoppingBasketInfo/Index`. It could only be used within the context of the main executing action.

Comment: I decided to go in a different direction in the end, but your answer seems simple and easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably a combination of Base Controller, Base View Model, Interface and Action Filter.

```
// Interface.  To be implemented by model and controller.
public interface IHoldABasket 
{
    Basket Basket { get; set; };
}

// Base view model.  Has a basket as public property.
public BaseBasketViewModel : IHoldABasket 
{
      public Basket Basket { get; set; }
}

// Base controller model.  Also has a basket.
public BaseController : Controller, IHoldABasket 
{
   public Basket Basket { get; set; }

   public BaseController() 
   {
       AttemptBasketLoad();
   }

   private void AttemptBasketLoad()
   {
       // Replace the SomeMethodToLoadBasket with whatever method you use
       // to retrieve a basket.
       Basket = SomeMethodToLoadBasket();
   }
}

// Action Filter
public class BasketAwareAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
{
   public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
   {
        // If controller can hold basket AND model can hold basket
        if (filterContext.Controller is IHoldABasket 
            && filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model is IHoldABasket)
        {
            // Copy basket from controller into model.
            // Will now be accessible through Basket property on model.
            ((IHoldABasket)filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model)
               .LoggedInUser
                = ((IHoldABasket)filterContext.Controller).LoggedInUser;

        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
   }
}
```

So that's the infrastructure sorted.  Let's look at a practical example.  You probably have a ProductListViewModel.  That should inherit from the base view model class.

First, make sure your ProductListViewModel inherits from BaseBasketViewModel.

```
public class ProductListViewModel : BaseBasketViewModel 
{
}
```

Because of the inheritance, your view model contains a basket object and implements the IHoldABasket interface.

Your controllers will inherit from BaseController.

```
public class ProductController : BaseController 
{

}
```

A controller method looks like this.

```
[BasketAware]
public ViewResult Products(int page = 1) 
{
   // Load VM that implements IHoldABasket
   // Really contrived, I know... :P

   var vm = new ProductListViewModel() { Results = productServices.Search() };

   return View(vm);
}
```

That should be it.  What's happening under the hood is

- Base controller attempts to load a basket, storing it if it finds one
- Controller and Model inherit a common interface, making the automated copy from controller to model easier to achieve.
- Action filter loads at the last minute.  If both controller and model can hold a basket (e.g. both implement `IHoldABasket`), the basket is copied from controller to model.
- All view models that derive from BaseBasketViewModel will have a public property called Basket.